# Get error while add HTTP Referrers for javascript Google Map API

Tags: google-maps

In the application that I am developing now  , I am using the JavaScript Google Map API with the input of latitude & longitude to get the location .
    Towards the API ,after adding my HTTP referrer i am ending up with the following error :

```
{
   "error_message" : "API keys with referrer restrictions cannot be used with this API.",
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

I added following HTTP referrer

- *.mydomain.com/*
      www.mydomain.com/*
      mydomain.com/*

Comment: Did you use google for that error?

Comment: remove the domain restriction.

Comment: @LeoNawroth yes I google for that error, all are mentioned what I mention above question in HTTP referrer part. I don’t know what I’m did wrong